# Is there a way to automatically create a changelist when checking out a new branch?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, changelist

I want Intellij IDEA to automatically create a new changelist containing the branches' name (which usually contains a JIRA-Ticket-Number) when checking it out so that commits contain it as well. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Each branch contains commits going back to the very initial commit. Do you want all that lengthy history? Or only what's original to a branch compared to some reference branch?

Comment: Not sure if you understood my question or I misunderstood your answer... Changelists are just a tool of intellij to group changes into lists. usually you have to create them manually.

Comment: I'm probably missing the picture since I know too little about IntelliJ, disregard my comment (maybe just off-topic)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve all that by setting up a Task server as per user guide:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-tasks-and-context.html#issue_tracker_integration

It allows you to configure JIRA server, set the behavior in terms changelists and commits

Comment: Thanks, I know about that functionality, but we have to create branches via JIRAs "create branch" functionality so (a branch is immediately connected to the JIRA-issue and has the issues name) and then check them out via IntelliJ. I dont want to create the branches via Intellij (or rather we cant).

Comment: @Vortilion if I understood you correctly - if you already have a branch and issue created in Jira, you need to "Open task" in Task & context and it should create a changelist for you.
But there is as well a known issue regarding chagelists:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-140006